# google map android - cannot set map icon from BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromAsset

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter

I am trying to use custom marker using marker image that is provided as `.bmp` file. I am building cross platform application using `Flutter` and this is the native code for Android. The image is from the assets in pubspec.yaml in flutter project.

```
  marker = map
       .addMarker(MarkerOptions()
       .position(annotation.coordinate)
       .title(annotation.title)
       .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromAsset("lib/green_circle.bmp")))
```

I got this error message for the code above:

> com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.b: Failed to
>   decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap.

I checked the image, and it's bmp
[image]

Comment: double check on image file, I think something problem with image

Comment: bmp? make it either png or jpg (not sure about webp)

Comment: @pskink I use .bmp because it's asking for bitmap image

Comment: so convert it to `.png` or `.jpg` (not sure about `.webp`)

Comment: I have tried `.png` and `.jpg` but getting the same error

Comment: what error its showing?

Comment: what does `context.getAssets().open("lib/green_circle.png")` return? does it throw `IOException`?

Comment: @pskink sorry I took on another which has higher priority. Anyway, where is the `context` come from? I have tried this from googling `getContext().getAssets().open("lib/green_circle.png")`, and I got `Unresolved reference: getContext()`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the way it handles the images. It does accept png, jpg and bmp, as I have tested with all of those, but I also had that same issue with some files of these formats (png and bmp).

What I did was open some of the files on another image editor, overwrite the files, and it worked. Weirdly, the files were normal png icons from Adobe Photoshop, and they didn't work.

If you have any issues or doubts, maybe try debugging with files from other sources, or editing it and saving it again.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error message for a different reason. My file was fine, but I provided an incorrect path to the file.

Make sure you get the directory and filename correct!